# PHP function - Call self with same (variable number) arguments

Tags: php, function, arguments

I have a PHP function that can take a variable number of arguments (and I use `func_get_args()` to process them)

```
class Test {

    private $ting = FALSE;

    public function test() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        if ($this->ting) {
            var_dump($args);
        } else {
            $this->ting = TRUE;
            $this->test($args); //I want to call the function again using the same arguments. (this is pseudo-code)
        }
    }

}
```

This function is not recursive (the "$ting" variable prevents it from going more than once).

I want test() to call itself using the same arguments it was given. So for example:
`Test->test("a", "b", "c");` would output the following:

`array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" }`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is looking for just a simple answer to the question in the title, this will call the current *class method* with the same arguments that were passed to it:

```
call_user_func_array([ $this, __FUNCTION__ ], func_get_args());
```

Or if it's a simple function (*not a method within a class*), you can do this:

```
call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `call_user_func_array`.

Example:

```
class TestClass {

    private $ting = FALSE;

    public function test() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        if ($this->ting) {
            var_dump($args);
        } else {
            $this->ting = TRUE;
            call_user_func_array(array($this, 'test'),$args);
        }
    }

}

$test = new TestClass();

//Outputs array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "apples" [1]=> string(7) "oranges" [2]=> string(5) "pears" }
$test->test("apples","oranges","pears");
```

Comment: why `&$this` rather than just `$this`?